# Adding columns to a data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.frame (or a matrix or any other tabular data structure object for that matter):

```
df = data.frame(field1 = c(1,1,1),field2 = c(2,2,2),field3 = c(3,3,3))
```

And I want to copy part of its columns - given in the vector below:

```
fields = c("field1","field2")
```

to a new data.table that already has 1 or more columns:

```
dt = data.table(fieldX = c("x","x","x"))
```

I'm looking for something more efficient (and elegant) than:

```
for(f in 1:length(fields))
{
dt[,fields[f]] = df[,fields[f]]
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Are you sure you mean [data.table](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/)?

Comment: This is just a toy example of a bigger problem that I really have. I have a tabular data structure object (with many fields) from which I want to copy several fields to a data.table.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use `cbind`:

```
cbind(dt, df[fields])
```

However, the most efficient way is still probably going to be to use `data.table`'s assign by reference:

```
dt[, (fields) := df[fields]]
```

Comment: Interestingly, it seems you can add columns simultaneously. For eg., `t = data.table(c1=1,c2=2); x = list(); x[1] <- 10; x[2] <- 100; invisible(foreach (i=1:2) %dopar% { input = x[[i]]; col = LETTERS[i]; t[ ,eval(col):= input] })`

Answer (score 4):

I think you want cbind

```
cbind(dt, df[, 1:2])
# fieldX field1 field2
# 1      x      1      2
# 2      x      1      2
# 3      x      1      2
```